# Is there a standardize method for writing statements combinations of (RF) signal flow path through a system?

Tags: filters, control-systems, signal-power

Let's say I am given a system block diagram of various components that either route/switch/amplify/filter and so on. Each of these components of the system perform these signal modifications or lack thereof. (for example, a Power Amplifier can also have an optional bypass path for the signal to take (and obviously the PA would be turned off if not used)). There would be many optional paths to take that essentially perform the same thing:

`in1` signal goes to PA. That output goes to a switch network that routes the signal through the expected filter. The output of that filter is connected an antenna (or more than one). The antenna is configured to only send that filtered, amped signal. And thus the final output.

[image: Example System]

#### Method #1

Could I write this as: `in1 -> (PA) -> (switch) -> filter_A_input -> (filter_A) -> filter_A_output -> ant_A_input -> (ANT) -> out1`? Would that be intuitive and easy to understand?

Now, let's say I have several combinations of routing the signal to antenna 1 or antenna 2. Could I write something like this and it be intuitive of what the combination options are? `in1 -> (PA) -> (switch) -> filter_A_input -> (filter_A) -> filter_A_output -> ant_A_input -> (ANT1/2) -> out1`

#### Method #2

Could I write it the way we learned signal processing in school: (in this case, just showing the path the signal takes throughout my system)

so instead of `y(t) = h(t) * x(t)`, have:

```
pa_out = PA * in1
filterA_in = SW * pa_out
filterA_out = FILT_A * filterA_in
out1 = (ANT1 || ANT2) * filterA_out
```

with many components, this would be quite long. How about `out1 = (ANT1 || ANT2) * FILT_A * SW * PA * in1`?

#### Comparison

These are the only two methods I can think of: 1) draw ascii arrows from the input to the component or pin name and 2) following the math-based equations learned during signals and systems. However, #1 doesn't seem universal or standard, although intuitive to me. And #2 is essentially expected from anyone with an EE education but may not cover use cases of several combinations in one line of text.

#### Footnote

I know I am asking a somewhat systems point-of-view question on how to write statements (NOT how to graph). However, I would imagine any signal processing engineer in their respective field has some standard used that is understandable for others, other than having to make markings and highlights on very large, complex system diagrams. The point isn't to solve a signal and figure out what the power and frequency (although helpful). It would be to describe, in as few words or text as possible the path of the signal, especially for use cases where there are many options to achieve the same output (either ANT1 or ANT2 can transmit; or if it was RX, I could use 3-4 filters to get 3-4 processed signals in various combinations to 3-4 different output paths).

Comment: Both methods are useful and commonplace. The first one is called a flowgraph. A third possibility is to modify the second method to be in the frequency (or $s$ or $z$) domains instead of time.

Comment: @MBaz how would the first method show different combinations of use cases? for example, if I had three signal outputs that can go to four optional antennas. i understand the first is common to show for simple node graphs, just not sure how it is written for a constrained use case that creates a combination of configured paths.

Comment: If you want the description to be human-readable, probably the best way is to define your nomenclature as precisely as you can -- there's no standard method I know of to describe many combinations of signal paths. An alternative would be to use a computer-based format (such as a gnuradio flowgraph) where you can define blocks and interconnections between them. HTH!

Comment: Perhaps there isn't a certified standard, but there has to be ways others have written statements of paths. And again, not flowgraphs. A written (series of) statement/equation/notation.